# How to remove distortions from image?

Tags: html, css

So, I have many images on my page, each image has different size and I want to make them look similarly.
I used `object-fit: cover;` to resize them but I got distorted images.

Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/Daniil111/pen/ZELENEq):

```css
div{
  width: 70vw;
  height: 130vh;
}
.image1{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.image2{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='image1' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'> <!-- distorted image -->
  <img class='image2' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'> <!-- how it should look like -->
</div>
```

Comment: I see different results in Chrome and Firefox but none look distorted to me, unless I'm not looking in the right place. Perhaps you can add a screenshot of what you see, or provide a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the quality of the image, `backface-visibility` will do the trick.

```css
div{
  width: 70vw;
  height: 130vh;
}
.image1{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.image2{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img class='image1' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'>
<!-- distorted image -->
<img class='image2' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'>
<!-- how it should look like -->
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work :(. There is still this "staircase effect", it's especially visible on the lattice on the front of car. It looks like there is only one way: resize all images manually

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the dimensions on the image?

```css
div{
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.image1{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
}
.image2{
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class='image1' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'> <!-- distorted image -->
</div>
<div>
  <img class='image2' src='https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/wV2RV/s1/bentley-continental-gt-mulliner-coupe.jpg'> <!-- how it should look like -->
</div>
```